# AVD "use host GPU" cause black screen when testing apps

Tags: android, cordova

i created a new project of phonegap 2.7, and open the project by using eclipse and android emulator with use "use GPU option" , here is the screenshot

If i don't use "use GPU option", the logo can be displayed, but the upper background is still in black.

[image]

there should be a logo at center blinking and with a grey background (no black), any one knows what is the problem?

```
    06-14 02:02:54.799: E/GLUtils(2290): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
06-14 02:02:54.799: E/TransferQueue(2290): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 5, srcTexId 2, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
06-14 02:02:54.860: E/GLUtils(2290): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
06-14 02:02:54.860: E/TransferQueue(2290): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 9, srcTexId 2, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
06-14 02:02:54.968: E/GLUtils(2290): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
06-14 02:02:54.968: E/TransferQueue(2290): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 13, srcTexId 2, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
06-14 02:02:55.027: E/GLUtils(2290): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
06-14 02:02:55.027: E/TransferQueue(2290): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 6, srcTexId 2, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
06-14 02:02:55.107: E/GLUtils(2290): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
06-14 02:02:55.107: E/TransferQueue(2290): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 10, srcTexId 2, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
06-14 02:02:55.147: E/GLUtils(2290): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
06-14 02:02:55.147: E/TransferQueue(2290): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 15, srcTexId 2, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
06-14 02:02:55.237: E/GLUtils(2290): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
06-14 02:02:55.237: E/TransferQueue(2290): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 7, srcTexId 2, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
06-14 02:02:55.277: E/GLUtils(2290): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
06-14 02:02:55.288: E/TransferQueue(2290): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 11, srcTexId 2, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
06-14 02:02:55.317: E/GLUtils(2290): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
06-14 02:02:55.327: E/TransferQueue(2290): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 16, srcTexId 2, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
06-14 02:02:55.357: E/GLUtils(2290): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
06-14 02:02:55.357: E/TransferQueue(2290): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 4, srcTexId 2, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
06-14 02:02:55.417: E/TransferQueue(2290): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 8, srcTexId 2, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
06-14 02:02:55.447: E/GLUtils(2290): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
06-14 02:02:55.457: E/TransferQueue(2290): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 12, srcTexId 2, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
```

Comment: This isn't a definitive answer, but here are some things that have made `WebView`s go black in my own (non-PhoneGap) projects: Setting `layout_width` and/or `layout_height` to `wrap_content` (or not setting them at all, if creating the WebView programmatically), not enabling Javascript when a page uses it, and not setting a content encoding for HTML documents (either as a header or in a `meta` tag). The last one is probably the most likely cause, but without looking at your code, it's difficult to know exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @david Brown i turn android:hardwareAccelerated to "false" in AndroidManifest.xml to solved the problem, but it can't enjoy the hardware Accelerate features (i use android studio now, and genymotion, have same problem.)

Comment: @hkinterview thanks! I left Use Host GPU on and set android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in both the <manifest> and <application> tags. Now the graphics load and I get fast performance!

Comment: @hkinterview could you pls write your comment as an answer? it works.

Answer (score 2):

I've also been experiencing these rendering glitches, using Cordova 3.0.2.

This was appearing when using the Cordova CLI on OSX with Intel HAX CPU enabled and Host GPU Enabled.

As the OP said, disabling the Host GPU the rendering glitches appear to stop.

However, it appears with Host GPU enabled, the rendering glitches disappear quickly if I navigate through 2/3 screens; albeit reappearing each time the application is started.

```
E/GLUtils ( 2003): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x502)
E/TransferQueue( 2003): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 12, srcTexId 3, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
```

Even once the rendering glitches appear to have stopped the error messages (above) are still being written to the log.

Not really an answer, but I'm happy to put up with the issues - now I know how to stop them if needed.

**ETA** : I've also tried to force H/W acceleration to be enabled via CSS (below) on the browser instance, incase that had some impact but to no avail.

```
body {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
           transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

This, in fact, caused the number of navigations required to resolve the glitches to increase.

Further tests show that it's not time dependant; not resolved by returning to the home screen;  not resolved by scrolling; the only way I've been able to make them disappear to to navigate back/forth between a number of screens.