# Strange distortion when trying out a Phonegap project in Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, cordova, genymotion

When I run a Phonegap 3.0 project in the Genymotion emulator, the app appears but with a strange distortion. The following should display the standard HelloWorld icon, but all I get is this :

[image]

but when I click on the tilt-button twice, the icon *is* displayed right.

The distortion does NOT happen when I run the app in the standard AVD emulator or directly on my phone.

Does anybody recognize this, and maybe has a cause or solution?

I'm wondering if there's something wrong with my app, or not...

***UPDATE:***
when I try an other Android image, like Nexus One - 4.1.1, the app DOES appear right.

Comment: Could be problems with your GPU. When I'm running GenyMotion, the screen is constantly flickering. That certainly has nothing to do with my app.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue with the regular AVD emulator.

The two comments on this question sorted it out for me, does it work for you too?: [AVD "use host GPU" cause black screen when testing apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079996/avd-use-host-gpu-cause-black-screen-when-testing-apps)

> @david Brown i turn android:hardwareAccelerated to "false" in AndroidManifest.xml to solved the problem, but it can't enjoy the hardware Accelerate features (i use android studio now, and genymotion, have same problem.) –  hkinterview Aug 26 at 7:28
>
> @hkinterview thanks! I left Use Host GPU on and set android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in both the  and  tags. Now the graphics load and I get fast performance! –  John Jelinek Sep 21 at 21:38